# Using a SVM to classify audio data

Tags: python, svm, audio-recognition

If I had 1000 audio files where three people are independently saying an animal at the same time, there can be 9 independent labels of animals. What features should I select from the audio file, and how should I normalize them to build the most accurate SVM to classify the audio files? For reference, I am doing this project in Python,so specific code examples and libraries would be very helpful. Thanks! -Joe

Comment: Why would you use an SVM for this (in 2023)? Sounds a bit like a school project.

Answer (score 0):

> there can be 9 independent labels of animals.

One assumes the three speakers are making uniform draws
from {opossum, anteater, roadrunner} or some similar
[urn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urn_problem).
In this case counting syllables (`3`) would be uninformative,
but for a different vocabulary we may see different results.
Simple techniques can isolate those three animals from one another.

For a less constrained input vocabulary, 50 ms or 20 ms
[MFCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel-frequency_cepstrum)
windows would be a pretty typical feature to train on.

Find a [pre-trained](https://openai.com/research/whisper) model
to tweak, or train from scratch.